# Using FPGA specific hardware components when writing RTL

Tags: fpga, design, hdl

I have heard at times that someone writing a digital circuit design may want to use actual primitives present on the FPGA directly in the design. This means including the library which contains those primitive definitions into our design and then instantiating them in it. Examples could be a memory block, DSP block, logic array block e.t.c. directly instantiated and connected into our design.

I have not done this yet and don't see when doing so is important. Why would someone want to do so? Does it effect the way we do simulation of the design?

We always like to write our circuit from higher level of abstraction, therefore, instantiating such blocks does not make much sense to me.

Comment: How about when you want to use a hardened pcie block, or a serdes that's on board?  Saves a lot of space that you can now use and enables things at speeds the fpga itself couldn't do.  Just an example.

Comment: There are many components that can not be described in generic VHDL or Verilog statements: Clock ressources (BUFG, DCM, PLL), I/O ports: (IDELAY, SERDES, MGT, ETH/MAC, PCIe, ...), Debug (JTAG), Reconfiguration (ICAP, ...), System control (temperature, ...), ... Besides that: sometimes it's required to use primitives by hand because synthesis has bugs or is not smart enough to find a good / the best solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start incorporating specific primitives into your design, that design is no longer portable — it is locked into the technology in which those primitives appear.

In order to simulate such a design, you need to have the manufacturer's simulation library for those primitives. Such libraries are often delivered as encrypted binary files, in order to prevent the release of proprietary information about the implementation of those primitives.

One thing that I often do when faced with the need to use such a primitive is to "wrap" the primitive in an outer module that has a more abstract interface that's specific to my application. This allows me to write a purely behavioral version for initial functional debugging, and also to find a different way to map that functionality onto a different vendor's proprietary technology.

Comment: thank you, but when/why should we need to do so in the first place?

Comment: Because it's the only way to take advantage of certain features of advanced chips. For example, it's easy to infer a basic RAM from an abstract array, but in order to get a true dual-clock FIFO with different input and output port widths, you pretty much need to go through the vendor's macro function generator.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, the synthesizer is good at inferring primitives. However, there are primitives that cannot be inferred. Sometimes it as simple as a dual port RAM with different port widths or a FIFO with no extra fabric logic. There are also things like DCMs and PLLs for generating and managing clocks that can't be inferred with pure HDL.

FPGAs in many cases also contain much larger and more specialized primitives such as serializers, PCIe endpoints, Ethernet MACs, or hard processor cores. These must be  specifically instantiated and configured in order to be usable.

Comment: Thank you, my question was under what circumstances would we want to instantiate the normal blocks like memory, DSP, logic blocks e.t.c? I have read somewhere that sometimes it can help in writing a more "robust" design which "takes advantage of the FPGA logic fabric structure". But I am not yet aware of any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes instantiated FIFOs will take advantage of specialized logic that the HDL compilation tools will not be able to use in an inferred design.  As a result it will be significantly faster.  You suffer in portability but gain in speed.